# Windows 10 UWP Beta Apps on Windows 10 Stable Build

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am wondering if there is a way to get Windows Beta UWP apps running on a stable build specifically I am talking about the old Microsoft Edge Legacy and the UWP File explorer. I am having issues with this though let me use Microsoft Edge Legacy as an example.

I have Microsoft Edge Legacy from Windows 10 Build 18947, when I try running this on Windows 10 Build 19041 (2004) I get an error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj1nM.png

Hey there, I am wondering if there is a way to get Windows Beta UWP apps running on a stable build specifically I am talking about the old Microsoft Edge Legacy and the UWP File explorer. I am having issues with this though let me use Microsoft Edge Legacy as an example.

I have Microsoft Edge Legacy from Windows 10 Build 18947, when I try running this on Windows 10 Build 19041 (2004) I get an error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXqAs.png

Something is blocking the MicrosoftEdge.exe file from Windows Insider builds from running on a stable version. I have tried using different versions of Windows 10 Stable and Windows 10 Insider builds and they all have the same effect.

Windows Event Viewer says this by the way if this is any help:

Unable to start a DCOM Server: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.19041.1.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge as Unavailable/Unavailable. The error: "2147958023" Happened while starting this command: "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe" -ServerName:MicrosoftEdge.AppXdnhjhccw3zf0j06tkg3jtqr00qdm0khc.mca

If anyone knows or has any ideas on how to get Windows Apps from Windows Insider builds running on a stable build please let me know, any help will be appreciated :)

Tried different versions of Edge and Windows 10 Tried installing trust root certificates Tried editing the certificate for the EXE and removing it.

Comment: Microsoft killed the ability to run Legacy Edge on any older version once they fully transitioned to Chromium Edge. Your inability to run Legacy Edge runs deeper than it being a UWP application from a Insider Preview build.